# Join syntax not being recognized by SSMS

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, ssms, intellisense, sql-server-2008r2-express

When I try to build a simple join query, all of the join syntax is not being recognized by the query editor (inner, outer, left, right join).

FULL and ON are still recognized. I have never seen this happen and there is nothing on the internet about basic syntax not being recognized in this SQL Server version. What am I missing?

[image: A more useful screenshot]

Comment: You haven't finished the join.  Should be `..._Reposta] CR ON CA.Id = CR.xxx` or somesuch.

Comment: I know it's incomplete and it even works if I type it right. But why isn't being highlighted/treated as syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a feature called [IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/intellisense-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15), telling you your syntax isn't correct (yet). You can [turn it off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/configure-intellisense-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15) if it bothers you, but the whole point of the feature is to highlight your syntax when it is incorrect or incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason. Now I understand exactly what happened.